# Logo does not fit navbar

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap

i followed the bootstrap way to build a navbar and a footer, but i am having some troubles with the navbar, i want to place an image that is my logo inside the navbar at the begining in the left, but the logo does not fit the column. I don't know why.

**here is my code:**

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img  src="img/logo1.png" class="img img-responsive" alt=""></a>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="/Register">Register</a></li>
            <li><a href="/Login">Login</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
```

**Image:**

[image: the problem]

i tried to add this css:

```
.navbar-brand
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.navbar-brand img
{
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

but then my image get to small, if i want to increase the size of the image the image stretch, i just want the image to maintain the size ratio, and fit the left side of the navbar, what is wrong here?

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/7k6CnXAoi7)

Comment: try to add  `padding-left:20px;` in your .navbar-brand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `navbar-brand` outside of `navbar-nav`

```
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="img/logo1.png" class="img img-responsive" alt="">
      </a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
      <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="/Register">Register</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Login">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

**[More Info](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-default)**

Comment: Can you provide proper working `fiddle` that would be much easier to debug.

Comment: Alright! this is happening because of your logo image, this image containing lost of transparent part, you need to crop image.

Comment: thanks, i downloaded the png image thaught it had no transparency :/

Comment: Glad! I could help you. :) and you should use proper way to add `navbar-brand`, as I above mentioned.

Comment: the world improves with guys like you, thanks a lot for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this..

```
.navbar-brand
{
   padding-left:20px;
   z-index:999;
   position:relative;
}
```

Comment: i dont want the logo to display in that place, i want it up, maybe you can't see the navbar but it is there